# Table too large for page

Tags: tables, spacing

I need to have the following in my thesis but it won't fit on the page. How can I move this 31 by 31 matrix to the left? Please help

```
\begin{table}
\centering
\caption{Covariance matrix of the binned distance modulus. }
\label{tab:cmub}
{\fontsize{6pt}{0.3em}
\setlength{\arraycolsep}{1pt}

\begin{align*}10^{-6}\left(\begin{array}{*{31}{r}}
21282 & -10840 & 1918 & 451 & 946 & 614 & 785 & 686 & 581 & 233 & 881 & 133 & 475 & 295 & 277 & 282 & 412 & 293 & 337 & 278 & 219 & 297 & 156 & 235 & 133 & 179 & -25 & -106 & 0 & 137 & 168
\\
& 28155 & -2217 & 1702 & 74 & 322 & 380 & 273 & 424 & 487 & 266 & 303 & 406 & 468 & 447 & 398 & 464 & 403 & 455 & 468 & 417 & 444 & 351 & 399 & 83 & 167 & -86 & 15 & -2 & 76 & 243
\\
&  & 6162 & -1593 & 1463 & 419 & 715 & 580 & 664 & 465 & 613 & 268 & 570 & 376 & 405 & 352 & 456 & 340 & 412 & 355 & 317 & 341 & 242 & 289 & 119 & 152 & -69 & -33 & -44 & 37 & 209
\\
&  &  & 5235 & -722 & 776 & 588 & 591 & 583 & 403 & 651 & 212 & 555 & 353 & 355 & 323 & 442 & 319 & 372 & 337 & 288 & 343 & 210 & 272 & 92 & 167 & -48 & -29 & -21 & 50 & 229
\\
&  &  &  & 7303 & -508 & 1026 & 514 & 596 & 315 & 621 & 247 & 493 & 320 & 375 & 290 & 383 & 286 & 350 & 300 & 269 & 313 & 198 & 251 & 99 & 126 & 18 & 46 & 13 & 10 & 203
\\
&  &  &  &  & 3150 & -249 & 800 & 431 & 358 & 414 & 173 & 514 & 231 & 248 & 221 & 293 & 187 & 245 & 198 & 175 & 231 & 126 & 210 & 103 & 170 & 51 & 66 & -8 & -51 & 308
\\
&  &  &  &  &  & 3729 & -88 & 730 & 321 & 592 & 188 & 546 & 316 & 342 & 290 & 389 & 267 & 341 & 285 & 252 & 301 & 189 & 242 & 122 & 159 & 35 & 72 & 30 & 28 & 255
\\
&  &  &  &  &  &  & 3222 & -143 & 568 & 421 & 203 & 491 & 257 & 280 & 240 & 301 & 221 & 275 & 227 & 210 & 249 & 148 & 220 & 123 & 160 & 43 & 69 & 27 & 7 & 253
\\
&  &  &  &  &  &  &  & 3225 & -508 & 774 & 156 & 502 & 273 & 323 & 276 & 370 & 260 & 316 & 273 & 231 & 273 & 171 & 226 & 111 & 154 & 0 & 29 & 19 & 23 & 206
\\
&  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & 5646 & -1735 & 691 & 295 & 362 & 316 & 305 & 370 & 280 & 346 & 313 & 276 & 310 & 217 & 274 & 131 & 175 & 38 & 118 & 78 & 48 & 303
\\
&  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & 8630 & -1642 & 944 & 152 & 253 & 184 & 274 & 202 & 254 & 233 & 196 & 237 & 156 & 207 & 27 & 115 & -32 & 7 & -15 & 0 & 176
\\
&  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & 3855 & -754 & 502 & 225 & 278 & 294 & 274 & 285 & 253 & 239 & 255 & 173 & 229 & 181 & 177 & 93 & 124 & 132 & 108 & 227
\\
&  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & 4340 & -634 & 660 & 240 & 411 & 256 & 326 & 276 & 235 & 290 & 184 & 256 & 135 & 222 & 90 & 152 & 67 & 17 & 318
\\
&  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & 2986 & -514 & 479 & 340 & 363 & 377 & 362 & 315 & 343 & 265 & 311 & 144 & 198 & 17 & 62 & 86 & 147 & 226
\\
&  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & 3592 & -134 & 606 & 333 & 422 & 374 & 333 & 349 & 267 & 300 & 157 & 184 & 9 & 71 & 85 & 136 & 202
\\
&  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & 1401 & 22 & 431 & 343 & 349 & 302 & 322 & 245 & 284 & 171 & 186 & 70 & 70 & 93 & 142 & 202
\\
&  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & 1491 & 141 & 506 & 386 & 356 & 394 & 278 & 306 & 188 & 212 & 79 & 71 & 106 & 145 & 240
\\
&  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & 1203 & 200 & 435 & 331 & 379 & 281 & 311 & 184 & 209 & 49 & 51 & 110 & 197 & 181
\\
&  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & 1032 & 258 & 408 & 398 & 305 & 330 & 197 & 223 & 78 & 79 & 113 & 174 & 225
\\
&  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & 1086 & 232 & 453 & 298 & 328 & 120 & 189 & -48 & 22 & 42 & 142 & 204
\\
&  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & 1006 & 151 & 329 & 282 & 169 & 195 & 58 & 80 & 95 & 192 & 188
\\
&  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & 1541 & 124 & 400 & 199 & 261 & 150 & 166 & 202 & 251 & 251
\\
&  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & 1127 & 72 & 227 & 222 & 93 & 118 & 93 & 171 & 161
\\
&  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & 1723 & -105 & 406 & -3 & 180 & 190 & 198 & 247
\\
&  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & 1550 & 144 & 946 & 502 & 647 & 437 & 215
\\
&  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & 1292 & 187 & 524 & 393 & 387 & 284
\\
&  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & 3941 & 587 & 1657 & 641 & 346
\\
&  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & 2980 & 360 & 1124 & 305
\\
&  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & 4465 & -1891 & 713
\\
&  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & 23902 & -1826
\\
&  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & 19169
\\
\end{array}\right)
\end{align*}
}
\end{table}
```

Comment: Please tell us which document class you employ, which text and math font is in use, what size paper you employ, and how tall and wide the text block is.

Answer (score 4):

like this:

[image]

or like this:

[image]

mwe for the first case:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[margin=25mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[strict]{changepage}
\usepackage{rotating}

%---------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%

    \begin{document}
\begin{table}
\begin{adjustwidth*}{-15mm}{-15mm}
\centering
\caption{Covariance matrix of the binned distance modulus. }
\label{tab:cmub}
\tiny%\fontsize{6pt}{0.3em}
\setlength{\arraycolsep}{1pt}
\begin{align*}10^{-6}\left(\begin{array}{*{31}{r}}
21282 & -10840 & 1918 & 451 & 946 & 614 & 785 & 686 & 581 & 233 & 881 & 133 & 475 & 295 & 277 & 282 & 412 & 293 & 337 & 278 & 219 & 297 & 156 & 235 & 133 & 179 & -25 & -106 & 0 & 137 & 168
\\
& 28155 & -2217 & 1702 & 74 & 322 & 380 & 273 & 424 & 487 & 266 & 303 & 406 & 468 & 447 & 398 & 464 & 403 & 455 & 468 & 417 & 444 & 351 & 399 & 83 & 167 & -86 & 15 & -2 & 76 & 243
\\
&  & 6162 & -1593 & 1463 & 419 & 715 & 580 & 664 & 465 & 613 & 268 & 570 & 376 & 405 & 352 & 456 & 340 & 412 & 355 & 317 & 341 & 242 & 289 & 119 & 152 & -69 & -33 & -44 & 37 & 209
\\
&  &  & 5235 & -722 & 776 & 588 & 591 & 583 & 403 & 651 & 212 & 555 & 353 & 355 & 323 & 442 & 319 & 372 & 337 & 288 & 343 & 210 & 272 & 92 & 167 & -48 & -29 & -21 & 50 & 229
\\
&  &  &  & 7303 & -508 & 1026 & 514 & 596 & 315 & 621 & 247 & 493 & 320 & 375 & 290 & 383 & 286 & 350 & 300 & 269 & 313 & 198 & 251 & 99 & 126 & 18 & 46 & 13 & 10 & 203
\\
&  &  &  &  & 3150 & -249 & 800 & 431 & 358 & 414 & 173 & 514 & 231 & 248 & 221 & 293 & 187 & 245 & 198 & 175 & 231 & 126 & 210 & 103 & 170 & 51 & 66 & -8 & -51 & 308
\\
&  &  &  &  &  & 3729 & -88 & 730 & 321 & 592 & 188 & 546 & 316 & 342 & 290 & 389 & 267 & 341 & 285 & 252 & 301 & 189 & 242 & 122 & 159 & 35 & 72 & 30 & 28 & 255
\\
&  &  &  &  &  &  & 3222 & -143 & 568 & 421 & 203 & 491 & 257 & 280 & 240 & 301 & 221 & 275 & 227 & 210 & 249 & 148 & 220 & 123 & 160 & 43 & 69 & 27 & 7 & 253
\\
&  &  &  &  &  &  &  & 3225 & -508 & 774 & 156 & 502 & 273 & 323 & 276 & 370 & 260 & 316 & 273 & 231 & 273 & 171 & 226 & 111 & 154 & 0 & 29 & 19 & 23 & 206
\\
&  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & 5646 & -1735 & 691 & 295 & 362 & 316 & 305 & 370 & 280 & 346 & 313 & 276 & 310 & 217 & 274 & 131 & 175 & 38 & 118 & 78 & 48 & 303
\\
&  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & 8630 & -1642 & 944 & 152 & 253 & 184 & 274 & 202 & 254 & 233 & 196 & 237 & 156 & 207 & 27 & 115 & -32 & 7 & -15 & 0 & 176
\\
&  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & 3855 & -754 & 502 & 225 & 278 & 294 & 274 & 285 & 253 & 239 & 255 & 173 & 229 & 181 & 177 & 93 & 124 & 132 & 108 & 227
\\
&  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & 4340 & -634 & 660 & 240 & 411 & 256 & 326 & 276 & 235 & 290 & 184 & 256 & 135 & 222 & 90 & 152 & 67 & 17 & 318
\\
&  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & 2986 & -514 & 479 & 340 & 363 & 377 & 362 & 315 & 343 & 265 & 311 & 144 & 198 & 17 & 62 & 86 & 147 & 226
\\
&  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & 3592 & -134 & 606 & 333 & 422 & 374 & 333 & 349 & 267 & 300 & 157 & 184 & 9 & 71 & 85 & 136 & 202
\\
&  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & 1401 & 22 & 431 & 343 & 349 & 302 & 322 & 245 & 284 & 171 & 186 & 70 & 70 & 93 & 142 & 202
\\
&  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & 1491 & 141 & 506 & 386 & 356 & 394 & 278 & 306 & 188 & 212 & 79 & 71 & 106 & 145 & 240
\\
&  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & 1203 & 200 & 435 & 331 & 379 & 281 & 311 & 184 & 209 & 49 & 51 & 110 & 197 & 181
\\
&  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & 1032 & 258 & 408 & 398 & 305 & 330 & 197 & 223 & 78 & 79 & 113 & 174 & 225
\\
&  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & 1086 & 232 & 453 & 298 & 328 & 120 & 189 & -48 & 22 & 42 & 142 & 204
\\
&  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & 1006 & 151 & 329 & 282 & 169 & 195 & 58 & 80 & 95 & 192 & 188
\\
&  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & 1541 & 124 & 400 & 199 & 261 & 150 & 166 & 202 & 251 & 251
\\
&  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & 1127 & 72 & 227 & 222 & 93 & 118 & 93 & 171 & 161
\\
&  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & 1723 & -105 & 406 & -3 & 180 & 190 & 198 & 247
\\
&  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & 1550 & 144 & 946 & 502 & 647 & 437 & 215
\\
&  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & 1292 & 187 & 524 & 393 & 387 & 284
\\
&  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & 3941 & 587 & 1657 & 641 & 346
\\
&  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & 2980 & 360 & 1124 & 305
\\
&  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & 4465 & -1891 & 713
\\
&  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & 23902 & -1826
\\
&  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & 19169
\\
\end{array}\right)
\end{align*}
\end{adjustwidth*}
\end{table}
    \end{document}
```

for the second case:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[margin=25mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{rotating}

%---------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%

\begin{document}
\begin{sidewaystable}
\begin{adjustwidth*}{-20mm}{-20mm}
\centering
\caption{Covariance matrix of the binned distance modulus. }
\label{tab:cmub}
\small
\setlength{\arraycolsep}{1pt}
%
%    table body
%
\end{adjustwidth*}
\end{sidewaystable} % in the second case
    \end{document}
```

in the first case table hasn't big value, because it is almost illegible. in the second case font size is bigger: instead `\tiny` can be used `small`.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming the paper size of our document is `A4`, that the margins are 2.5cm all around, that the font in use is Computer Modern, and that the main document font size is `10pt`, it's (just) possible to fit the matrix inside the textblock by (a) using landscape mode (via a `sidewaystable` environment), (b) employing `\footnotesize` for a 20% linear reduction in font size, (c) severely reducing the value of `\arraycolsep` (1.333pt instead of the default 5pt), (d) using a `pmatrix*` environment for more compact spacing and, last but not least, (e) moving the mention of the common multiplicative factor (`10^6`) out of the equation itself.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{mathtools} % for 'pmatrix*' env.
\setcounter{MaxMatrixCols}{31} % default value: 10
\usepackage{rotating} % for 'sidewaystable' env.
\begin{document}
\begin{sidewaystable}
\caption{Covariance matrix of the binned distance modulus.}
\label{tab:cmub}
\setlength{\arraycolsep}{1.333pt} % default: 5pt
\footnotesize % 20% linear reduction in font size

Note: All numbers are multiplied by $10^6$.

\bigskip
$\begin{pmatrix*}[r]
21282 & -10840 & 1918 & 451 & 946 & 614 & 785 & 686 & 581 & 233 & 881 & 133 & 475 & 295 & 277 & 282 & 412 & 293 & 337 & 278 & 219 & 297 & 156 & 235 & 133 & 179 & -25 & -106 & 0 & 137 & 168
\\
& 28155 & -2217 & 1702 & 74 & 322 & 380 & 273 & 424 & 487 & 266 & 303 & 406 & 468 & 447 & 398 & 464 & 403 & 455 & 468 & 417 & 444 & 351 & 399 & 83 & 167 & -86 & 15 & -2 & 76 & 243
\\
&  & 6162 & -1593 & 1463 & 419 & 715 & 580 & 664 & 465 & 613 & 268 & 570 & 376 & 405 & 352 & 456 & 340 & 412 & 355 & 317 & 341 & 242 & 289 & 119 & 152 & -69 & -33 & -44 & 37 & 209
\\
&  &  & 5235 & -722 & 776 & 588 & 591 & 583 & 403 & 651 & 212 & 555 & 353 & 355 & 323 & 442 & 319 & 372 & 337 & 288 & 343 & 210 & 272 & 92 & 167 & -48 & -29 & -21 & 50 & 229
\\
&  &  &  & 7303 & -508 & 1026 & 514 & 596 & 315 & 621 & 247 & 493 & 320 & 375 & 290 & 383 & 286 & 350 & 300 & 269 & 313 & 198 & 251 & 99 & 126 & 18 & 46 & 13 & 10 & 203
\\
&  &  &  &  & 3150 & -249 & 800 & 431 & 358 & 414 & 173 & 514 & 231 & 248 & 221 & 293 & 187 & 245 & 198 & 175 & 231 & 126 & 210 & 103 & 170 & 51 & 66 & -8 & -51 & 308
\\
&  &  &  &  &  & 3729 & -88 & 730 & 321 & 592 & 188 & 546 & 316 & 342 & 290 & 389 & 267 & 341 & 285 & 252 & 301 & 189 & 242 & 122 & 159 & 35 & 72 & 30 & 28 & 255
\\
&  &  &  &  &  &  & 3222 & -143 & 568 & 421 & 203 & 491 & 257 & 280 & 240 & 301 & 221 & 275 & 227 & 210 & 249 & 148 & 220 & 123 & 160 & 43 & 69 & 27 & 7 & 253
\\
&  &  &  &  &  &  &  & 3225 & -508 & 774 & 156 & 502 & 273 & 323 & 276 & 370 & 260 & 316 & 273 & 231 & 273 & 171 & 226 & 111 & 154 & 0 & 29 & 19 & 23 & 206
\\
&  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & 5646 & -1735 & 691 & 295 & 362 & 316 & 305 & 370 & 280 & 346 & 313 & 276 & 310 & 217 & 274 & 131 & 175 & 38 & 118 & 78 & 48 & 303
\\
&  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & 8630 & -1642 & 944 & 152 & 253 & 184 & 274 & 202 & 254 & 233 & 196 & 237 & 156 & 207 & 27 & 115 & -32 & 7 & -15 & 0 & 176
\\
&  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & 3855 & -754 & 502 & 225 & 278 & 294 & 274 & 285 & 253 & 239 & 255 & 173 & 229 & 181 & 177 & 93 & 124 & 132 & 108 & 227
\\
&  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & 4340 & -634 & 660 & 240 & 411 & 256 & 326 & 276 & 235 & 290 & 184 & 256 & 135 & 222 & 90 & 152 & 67 & 17 & 318
\\
&  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & 2986 & -514 & 479 & 340 & 363 & 377 & 362 & 315 & 343 & 265 & 311 & 144 & 198 & 17 & 62 & 86 & 147 & 226
\\
&  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & 3592 & -134 & 606 & 333 & 422 & 374 & 333 & 349 & 267 & 300 & 157 & 184 & 9 & 71 & 85 & 136 & 202
\\
&  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & 1401 & 22 & 431 & 343 & 349 & 302 & 322 & 245 & 284 & 171 & 186 & 70 & 70 & 93 & 142 & 202
\\
&  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & 1491 & 141 & 506 & 386 & 356 & 394 & 278 & 306 & 188 & 212 & 79 & 71 & 106 & 145 & 240
\\
&  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & 1203 & 200 & 435 & 331 & 379 & 281 & 311 & 184 & 209 & 49 & 51 & 110 & 197 & 181
\\
&  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & 1032 & 258 & 408 & 398 & 305 & 330 & 197 & 223 & 78 & 79 & 113 & 174 & 225
\\
&  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & 1086 & 232 & 453 & 298 & 328 & 120 & 189 & -48 & 22 & 42 & 142 & 204
\\
&  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & 1006 & 151 & 329 & 282 & 169 & 195 & 58 & 80 & 95 & 192 & 188
\\
&  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & 1541 & 124 & 400 & 199 & 261 & 150 & 166 & 202 & 251 & 251
\\
&  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & 1127 & 72 & 227 & 222 & 93 & 118 & 93 & 171 & 161
\\
&  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & 1723 & -105 & 406 & -3 & 180 & 190 & 198 & 247
\\
&  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & 1550 & 144 & 946 & 502 & 647 & 437 & 215
\\
&  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & 1292 & 187 & 524 & 393 & 387 & 284
\\
&  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & 3941 & 587 & 1657 & 641 & 346
\\
&  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & 2980 & 360 & 1124 & 305
\\
&  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & 4465 & -1891 & 713
\\
&  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & 23902 & -1826
\\
&  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & 19169
\end{pmatrix*}$
\end{sidewaystable}
\end{document}
```